# Peer Pressure badge on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, meta, peer-pressure-badge

I've now deleted two different answers of mine on Meta, and haven't seen a Peer Pressure badge.  Does this badge not work correctly on Meta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that it takes awhile for the Peer Pressure badge to be awarded. Mine took about a week.

Comment: Same experience here.

Comment: Yes, either delay or bug: 20 hours ago a user deleted an answer (-3) here: http://serverfault.com/questions/50386/what-is-the-difference-between-hosts-and-lmhosts-files and didn't get the badge.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that the posts had 3 more down-votes than up-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [someone has it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/36/peer-pressure)...

Comment: Hell yeah I do. I belong to the "My answer sucked and now I leave in shame" club. Btw, yesterday, I was a one-dude club. So that's four in the past day alone. Welcome, my fellow awful answerers!