# Peer Pressure badge worded incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, peer-pressure-badge, badge-description

According to the [Peer Pressure page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure), the badge is awarded to those who "deleted [their] own post with 3 or more downvotes." I [did this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583869/why-is-the-use-of-shift-without-parentheses-is-ambiguous-warning-issued-by-pe/1583882#1583882) recently and didn't get the badge. The answer in question had 3 downvotes, but also had 4 upvotes. Either clarify the Peer Pressure badge to say "Deleted own post with a score of -3" or change the badge's implementation (and do the same for Disciplined, since I assume they're implemented the same way).

Comment: See here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/peer-pressure-badge-on-meta

Comment: Knowing that the wording is, in fact, wrong doesn't fix the wording issue.

Comment: The title of this question is worded *poorly*

Answer (score 7):

This has long been fixed. The [current description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure) is

> Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower.

Comment: please look at the timestamp of the question...

Comment: The question is old, but it still deserves an answer.

Comment: @Gamecat please see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133918/167443)